# How to integrate report portal to pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, reportportal

First of all I tried "ReportPortal listener"

`<plugin>`
   `<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>`
   `<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>`
   `<version>2.15</version>`
   `<configuration>`
      `<properties>`
         `<property>`
            `<name>listener</name>`
            `<value>com.epam.reportportal.junit.ReportPortalListener</value>`
         `</property>`
      `</properties>`
   `</configuration>`
`</plugin>`

But tests gave me error

`at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)`

Then I tried to write
`@RunWith(com.epam.reportportal.junit.CustomJUnitRunner.class)`

But system couldn't find and import `com.epam.reportportal.junit.CustomJUnitRunner.class`

Maybe someone knows how to do this integration?

Answer (score 0):

@noPainNoGain, we host packages on bintray.

add repository as well

```
   <repositories>
     <repository>
        <snapshots>
          <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>bintray-epam-reportportal</id>
        <name>bintray</name>
        <url>http://dl.bintray.com/epam/reportportal</url>
     </repository>
</repositories>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.epam.reportportal</groupId>
  <artifactId>agent-java-testng</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- TODO Leave only one dependency, depends on what logger you use: -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.epam.reportportal</groupId>
  <artifactId>logger-java-logback</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.epam.reportportal</groupId>
  <artifactId>logger-java-log4j</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

https://github.com/reportportal/agent-java-testNG#dependencies

Comment: It helps only for testng.

Comment: check the latest junit4. it was completly rebuild https://github.com/reportportal/agent-java-junit